# Заменить несколько возможных точек одной

Tags: php

Всем привет. Использую PHP 5.6
Имеется строка с текстом, который может заканчиваться (а может и НЕ заканчиваться) несколькими подряд идущими точками. Если в конце строки есть несколько точек - нужно заменить их одной точкой.

rtrim($str, '.') тут не подходит - он удалит все точки.
Добавить точку после этого тоже не подходит - если точек не было, то добавлять не нужно.

Вариант с регулярным выражением затратный и не самый изящный.
Может быть есть простой и быстрый вариант решения данной задачи?
Текст может быть на самых разных языках - русском, французком, китайском, польском и т.д.

Comment: если в конце несколько точек - нужно заменить их одной. а если строка не заканчивается точкой - нужна точка в конце?

Comment: странно вообще говорить про затраность регулярок и при этом сидеть на пхп 5.6. вы в каком объеме там данные обрабатывате, гигабайты что ли?

Comment: добавь точку после trim и все

Comment: Nikita Umnov, я же написал - строка с текстом может заканчиваться (а может и НЕ заканчиваться) точкой. Если она не заканчивается точкой, значит там или ! или ? - значит получится !. или ?. Я в вопросе написал "rtrim($str, '.') тут не подходит"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = 'Строка с несколькими точками в конце...';
$last_char = mb_substr($str, -1); // Получим последний символ
// Если строка оканчивается на точку, удалим все точки в конце и добавим одну
if($last_char == '.') $str = rtrim($str, '.') . '.'; 

echo $str; // Строка с несколькими точками в конце.
```

Comment: Зачем тут условие?

Comment: @tutankhamun, потому что в задании сказано: `Добавить точку после этого тоже не подходит - если точек не было, то добавлять не нужно.`

Answer (score -2):

Нужно получить длину строки (strlen($str)) и пройтись с конца с условием, где проверить наличие точки '.'. 
Если точки нет, добавить в конец, если есть посчитать сколько их пока будет не точка и обрезать строку.
Вот на скорую руку.

```
<?php
$str = 'abcdef sa...';
$i = strlen($str)-1; 
do {
    if ($str[$i] == ".") $i--;
     else if ($str[$i] !== "." ) {
         $str = substr($str, 0, $i).'.';
         break;
     }
} while ($i !=0);

echo $str;
?>
```